# Can I add to Combobox's model a different value than String?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox

I've created a **Java Application Project in Netbeans**. This project has the main class **JFrame form**. There is, inter alia, *Combo Box*. I need to add a quadratic function to this *Combobox*. And I really don't want to use for squared anything like this 
**^2** .

I've thought, that function might be represented by ,for example, .png file.(Like setting icon of buttons).

- Is it possible to add a picture to the model of Combo Box?
- Can be model of Combobox different than String?
- Or any idea, how to add a function to the Combo Box without **^** or **_** ?

I have this idea for few days, but I really don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "yes".

The responsibility for displaying the value in the combo box comes down to the `ListCellRenderer`

Take a look at [How to use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for details and [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for specifics

[image: Example]

*Image from How to use Combo Boxes trail*

Of course, how you achieve this is entirely up to you.  I would encourage you to put something easily identifiable in the model and then let the renderer figure out how to render it.  This is kind of important as you will need to know what the user has selected and identify it at some stage, and an `Image` might not be the best solution for this.